# HttpServlet Request Get Remote User truncating zeroes from the Beginning of User Id

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch UserId from HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser(). While fetching the UserIds starting with 0 , the 0s are getting truncated. I am using Kerberos authentication for the same.
How to fetch the User Ids without truncating the 0s...

Kindly Help.

Comment: What type is the user ID?

Comment: Its a String.....Set through Kerberos Authentication

Comment: We need a lot more information, at least including the code you're using to read it and to talk to Kerberos.